# Meaning of "You not like me"

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage, phrase-meaning, learning, dialect

I was listening to the song ["You not like me"](http://genius.com/50-cent-u-not-like-me-lyrics) by 50 cent. 50 uses the phrase in the hook many times,

> If you get shot and run to the cops you not like me
>   You ain't got no work on the block, you not like me
>   It's hot, you ain't got no drop, you not like me
>   Like me dude, you not like me

I think The sentence should be

> You *are* not like me.

I guess the original version is peculiar to AAVE. Please tell me what does it mean, when and where is it used? Etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the phrase should be "You are not like me". One of the reasons it's phrased as such is the context of the song-- the singer is in a rough area, and is supposedly not educated to the extent they could be.

It most likely also helps keep the song to the rhythm of the song, too.

### Edit:

Regarding your comment-- no, it's not a usual phrase in speech. It might be more common in groups where being well-spoken isn't such a priority, though. Whilst it might be more common in colloquial speech, I can't recommend using it.

Comment: So it is not a dialect use?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it in speech, no.

Comment: Is it offensive or abusive? Is it AAVE grammar or intentional use of wrong grammar.

Comment: I believe it's an intentional use of wrong grammar, but it's not offensive or abusive! :)

Comment: What does the 'no' mean at the end of your comment "*I wouldn't recommend using it in speech, **no***"? Does it emphasize the recommendation?

Comment: @user31782 Yes, it does! The part of my sentence makes a statement, and the second part answers your question directly.